# Screen shot with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I'm building a small app with Node.js, that can make a screen shot of a web page - from top to bottom, side to side. I wanna save a new image every time the page changes.

I'm using a 3rd party lib called [webshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webshot) to do it, and it's easy to use. BUT! The website I'm capturing uses lazy loading on the images. That's a challenge for webshot, and all I see is grey placeholder images on the web site.

First I tried to insert a delay after page is loaded - webshot has an option for this. I set it to 10 secs, but it only managed to get a handful of pictures in the screen shot...

The next solution I wanted to try was preloading all images on the page. So I imported [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) (html parser for node) and collected all  on the page and started preloading the usual way:

```
var src = image.attr("src");
var img = new Image();
img.src = src;
```

Unfortunately this does not work with Node.js. I get this error:

> "ReferenceError: Image is not defined"

Image can be obtained as a part of the [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) npm module. So I did `npn install canvas`. But unfortunately it's apparently not as simple as that... I found long tedious explanations on how to install a bunch of other libraries, which in order to install "canvas". Like this for example:

https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX

I'm on a mac and El Capitan. Seems like there's a problem:

https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/225

It seems complicated, and I can't figure out what the problem is. It seems unnecessary hard to create a simple Image element, and set it's source for it to load.

So my question is:

- Could the Image preloading be done differently in Node.js?
- How can I use create Images in Node.js without the dreadful Canvas lib??
- Are there any better options that webshot?

Thanks 
Ole

Comment: preloading the image doesn't really make sense in this case. Instead, you need webshot to simulate scrolling from top to bottom, thus causing the images to be pulled in by whatever is doing the lazy loading. but, i've never used webshot, so no idea if that is even possible.

Comment: The `renderDelay` option might help, but that will depend on how exactly the 3rd party site is handling lazy loading. the render delay would only handle delayed image loading, it wouldn't handle the case where the 3rd party site requires the image to become "in view" to be loaded.

Comment: @KevinB I thought about scrolling. But it seems much smarter to preload images AND THEN make screen shot. Its much more work to make scrolling,,, Or so it seems...

Comment: @KevinB I used renderDelay as I write (delay after page load). It does not work.

Comment: what does preloading the images solve? preloading the image won't make the src of the image in the html update to what it should be rather than the placeholders.

Comment: You have fulfil the requirements of the 3rd party page in order to have the placeholders be replaced with the actual images.

Comment: @KevinB I see what you mean. I agree that I need to scroll down the page in order for the 'src' attributes to change to correct image urls. 

Unfortunately PhantomJS seems to be very tricky to get working. I tried almost anything. Would it be possible to use node-webshot (based on phantomJS) to do it? Also, does anyone have example code on how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Well first, make sure Cairo is installed - I recommend using Brew and NOT MacPorts.  Also make sure all the dependencies are Linked in Brew, which was something that I had trouble with too.

So, there are a lot of issues with the latest version of Node Canvas and Cairo.  I spent a lot of time lately trying to get Node Canvas to work for a Card Creation tool I'm building to automate combining art on a server.

I believe the problem you're seeing is an issue with the version of Cairo. I wrote up a blog post with longer explanation on all the issues I had and how I resolved them (top half of the post):  http://blog.wakeskaterstudio.com/2015/10/card-creator-automating-card-creation.html

But essentially what you should try is:  Installing Cairo with Brew - get the latest version and make sure you check Brew to have all of the dependencies installed correctly.

Next, uninstall JUST Cairo (but leave all the dependencies) with Brew and manually go install version 1.12.X from the Cairo FTP Releases Page.

You might be able to use the lastest version of Cairo if you aren't using fonts at all, but I could not get them to work correctly with the latest version.  I also had issues with the latest version of node canvas, so I hard set that to 1.1.0 in my package.json.

I'm not sure this is EXACTLY the issue you're facing, but having Cairo 1.12.X and node canvas 1.1.0 seems to work very well for me.

Comment: OK thanks. It seems way too over complicated. Also as pointed out in a comment above, preloading images does not solve my problem. I need to scroll down the page to replace img.src's with correct urls.

Comment: Oh yeah true, you would need the correct src to load it properly.  Was that the issue though?  A reference error of Image not defined seems like you never loaded the Cairo library properly so node-canvas wasn't able to create the Image class and therefore it was undefined.